# OAuth 2.0 using Spring Security + WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jersey, wso2-identity-server

I'm developing a web application to expose a number of RESTful services secured by OAuth 2.0. Here is the planned architecture:

**1- OAuth Authorization Provider:** WSO2 Identity Server (IS)

**2- OAuth Resource Server:** Java web application using the following technologies:

- Jersey (to implement and expose the web services)
- Spring Security (to implement the OAuth Resource Server part)

I've seen several examples ([ex1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/2-legged+OAuth+for+Securing+a+RESTful+Service), [ex2](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/), [ex3](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/07/integrating-3-legged-oauth-with-xacml.html), etc...) on how to secure RESTful services using WSO2 IS as an authorization server + WSO2 ESB as a resource server. This is NOT what I need in my case.

Unfortunately, the interaction between the authorization server and the resource server is beyond the scope of the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-6). So, I couldn't find much about how should it look like.

Here are my questions:

- How to configure spring security to act as a resource server to validate an access token issued by an external OAuth provider (e.g. WSO2 IS)?
- How should the resource server identify the scope of a given access token?
- How to identify the resource owner given an access token from WSO2 IS?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this answered?  I'd be interested to know...

Unfortunately I have been asking some questions on wso2 is which have gone unanswered so far.

Comment: @ShyamalPandya Yes, I figured out how to do it myself. I'm planning to post the complete solution shortly. Till then, let me know if you have specific questions that I can help you with.

Comment: @ShyamalPandya I've posted the solution. I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After doing some research, I figured out how to do it. The solution is divided into 2 main parts: **WSO2 IS configuration** & **Resources server configuration**.

The basic scenario goes as follows:

1- A client (e.g. mobile app) consume a secured resource (e.g. web service) by sending a request to the resources sever (Java web application in my case).

2- The resources server validates the "Authorization" header in the request and extracts the access token.

3- The resources server validates the access token by sending it to the authorization server (WSO2 IS).

4- The authorization server responds with validation response.

5- The resources server validates the response and decides whether to grant or deny access to the requested resource.

In my demo, I used WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and Spring security 3.1.0.

---

### 1- WSO2 IS Configuration

WSO2 IS will act as the **authorization server**. So, it should be configured to support OAuth 2.0. To do so, a new service provider should be added and configured as follows:

(a) Login to WSO2 IS management console.

(b) Add a new service provider and give it a name and description.

[image: Service provider configuration: screenshot 1]

(c) Under **Inbound Authentication Configuration** >> **OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration** >> Click **Configure**.

(d) Configure OAuth 2.0 provider as shown in the below screenshot and click **Add**. We'll need **Password** grant type which maps to **Resource Owner Password Credentials** grant type. It is best suited for my case (securing web services).

[image: Service provider configuration: screenshot 2]

(e) Under **OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration**, you'll find **OAuth Client Key** and **OAuth Client Secret** generated. They are used along with username, password, and scope to generate access tokens.

---

### 2- Resources Server Configuration

As mentioned earlier, the demo Java web application will act as **Resources server** and client at the same time. To act as resources server, Spring security needs to know how to validate access tokens. So, a token services implementation should be provided.

(a) Configure spring to act as resources server. Here is a sample configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="com.example.security.oauth2.wso2.TokenServiceWSO2" />

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />

    <oauth2:resource-server id="resourcesServerFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <security:http pattern="/services/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="resourcesServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

Here, a **resource-server** that uses a token services implementation **TokenServiceWSO2** is configured. The **resource-server** tag is actually transformed to a security filter. An interception pattern is added to "/services/**" and the resources sever filter is added to the chain.

(b) Implement OAuth 2.0 token services **ResourceServerTokenServices**. The implementation will take an access token as an input, pass it to **OAuth2TokenValidationService** service exposed by WSO2 IS, validate the response and return a processed object containing the basic data about the token's issuer, validity, scope, corresponding JWT token, ...

```
public class TokenServiceWSO2 implements ResourceServerTokenServices {

    @Autowired
    TokenValidatorWSO2 tokenValidatorWSO2;

    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken) throws AuthenticationException, InvalidTokenException {

        try {
            TokenValidationResponse validationResponse = tokenValidatorWSO2.validateAccessToken(accessToken);
            OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request(null, null, null, true, validationResponse.getScope(), null, null, null,null);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(validationResponse.getAuthorizedUserIdentifier(), null, null);
            OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Request, authentication);
            return oAuth2Authentication;
        } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }

    public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        // TODO Add implementation
    }

}
```

**TokenValidatorWSO2** class implements the logic to call WSO2 IS's web service **OAuth2TokenValidationService**

```
@Component
public class TokenValidatorWSO2 implements OAuth2TokenValidator{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TokenValidatorWSO2.class);

    @Value("${server_url}")
    private String serverUrl;

    @Value("${validation_service_name}")
    private String validationServiceName;

    @Value("${comsumer_key}")
    private String consumerKey;

    @Value("${admin_username}")
    private String adminUsername;

    @Value("${admin_password}")
    private String adminPassword;

    private OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub stub;

    private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 15 * 60 * 1000;

    public TokenValidationResponse validateAccessToken(String accessToken) throws ApplicationException {
        logger.debug("validateAccessToken(String) - start");

        if(stub == null) {
            initializeValidationService();
        }

        OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO  oauthRequest;
        TokenValidationResponse validationResponse;
        OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO_OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken;

        try {
            oauthRequest = new OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO();
            oAuth2AccessToken = new OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO_OAuth2AccessToken();
            oAuth2AccessToken.setIdentifier(accessToken);
            oAuth2AccessToken.setTokenType("bearer");
            oauthRequest.setAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);
            OAuth2TokenValidationResponseDTO response = stub.validate(oauthRequest);

            if(!response.getValid()) {
                throw new ApplicationException("Invalid access token");
            }

            validationResponse = new TokenValidationResponse();
            validationResponse.setAuthorizedUserIdentifier(response.getAuthorizedUser());
            validationResponse.setJwtToken(response.getAuthorizationContextToken().getTokenString());
            validationResponse.setScope(new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(response.getScope())));
            validationResponse.setValid(response.getValid());

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error("validateAccessToken() - Error when validating WSO2 token, Exception: {}", ex);
        }

        logger.debug("validateAccessToken(String) - end");
        return validationResponse;
    }

    private void initializeValidationService() throws ApplicationException {
        try {
            String serviceURL = serverUrl + validationServiceName;
            stub = new OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub(null, serviceURL);
            CarbonUtils.setBasicAccessSecurityHeaders(adminUsername, adminPassword, true, stub._getServiceClient());
            ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
            Options options = client.getOptions();
            options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
            options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
            options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
            options.setCallTransportCleanup(true);
            options.setManageSession(true);
        } catch(AxisFault ex) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

**TokenValidationResponse** class holds the basic data returned in token validation response.

```
public class TokenValidationResponse {

    private String jwtToken;
    private boolean valid;
    private Set<String> scope;
    private String authorizedUserIdentifier;

    public String getJwtToken() {
        return jwtToken;
    }

    public void setJwtToken(String jwtToken) {
        this.jwtToken = jwtToken;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    public Set<String> getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(Set<String> scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public String getAuthorizedUserIdentifier() {
        return authorizedUserIdentifier;
    }

    public void setAuthorizedUserIdentifier(String authorizedUserIdentifier) {
        this.authorizedUserIdentifier = authorizedUserIdentifier;
    }
}
```

---

### 3- Client Application Configuration

The last step is to configure the resources to be protected by OAuth 2.0. Basically, configure the web services to be secured with a root URL path "/services/**". In my demo, I used Jersey.

---

### 4- Test The Client Application

The last step is to consume the secured web services. This is done by adding **Authorization** header to the request with value " ", for example "**bearer 7fbd71c5b28fdf0bdb922b07915c4d5**".

---

P.S. The described sample is just for clarification purposes. It may be missing some implementations, exception handling, ... Kindly comment for further inquiries.

Comment: can you share the source code? thank you very much

Comment: @VũBáQuang Sorry, I don't have access to the source code anymore. It was created a long time ago.