# Spring Security OAuth 2.0 - Creating a custom resource server

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jersey

I'm configuring Spring Security OAuth 2.0 to secure a number of Jersey exposed REST services. I'll be using an external identity server as the authorization server. It'll be responsible for issuing and storing access tokens to its own token store. So, token validation process should be done against this server through a validation web service.

How should I configure Spring Security to work only as a resource server?

All the examples I found uses Spring Security to create both authorization server and resource server (which have access to the token store). This is not possible in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how do it. A sample configuration is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211444/746741), I hope it would be useful for someone in the future.